# Batch File not running, command works from CMD. IP Change

Tags: windows

I am trying to get a basic IP change batch file to work. The commands I am using work in command prompt.

Batch File:

```
@echo off
netsh interface ipv4 set address name=”Ethernet” static 192.168.1.236 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
@echo off
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name=”Ethernet” static 8.8.8.8
pause
```

I am attempting to use this and another batch that sends it back to DHCP. This file worked 1 time, but doesn't work anymore. I am opening the file as administrator.

I can run these commands in CMD and they work fine. Any suggestions?
- Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I got this script off of Stack someplace once apon a batch code search. I have modified the DNS to use Google's DNS for the Primary and Secondary DNS's and also made some cosmetic changes for use in one of my own scripts but i'm sure it will answer your question. its has worked alright for me.

All the IP Address are default network setup address with exception to the DNS, you will have to change them manually in a TXT file for your own uses. Just save it as a batch script, if you have a problem, I can find and post the original code, I have it backed up on a cloud somewhere, just send me a message.

Hope it helps.

```
:again
cls
TITLE Ip Changer
ECHO ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ECHO ~  1. Change stack to static IP address, mask, and DNS Server(s) ~
ECHO ~  2. Change stack to DHCP network configuration                 ~
ECHO ~  3. Change stack to SB200 IP configuration                     ~
ECHO ~  4. Change stack to SB600B IP configuration                    ~
ECHO ~  5. Change stack to T_U configuration                          ~
ECHO ~  6. Change stack to T_P configuration                          ~
ECHO ~  7. Main Menu                                                  ~
ECHO ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

SET /p choice=
IF /I [%choice%]==[1] GOTO Static
IF /I [%choice%]==[2] GOTO DHCP
IF /I [%choice%]==[3] GOTO SB200
IF /I [%choice%]==[4] GOTO SB600
IF /I [%choice%]==[5] GOTO T_U
IF /I [%choice%]==[6] GOTO T_P
IF /I [%choice%]==[7] GOTO menu
CLS
ECHO INCORRECT CHOICE CHOOSE AGAIN
GOTO again
PAUSE>NUL
ECHO.

:Static
ECHO.
SET /P Addy=IP Address:
SET /P Sub_Mask=Subnet Mask:
SET /P GW=Gateway IP Address:
SET /P DNS_1=Primary DNS Server:
SET /P DNS_2=Secondary DNS Server:

netsh interface ip SET address "Local Area Connection" static %Addy% %Sub_Mask% %GW% 1
netsh interface ip delete dns "Local Area Connection" all

IF NOT [%DNS_1%]==[] netsh interface ip SET dns "Local Area Connection" static %DNS_1%
IF NOT [%DNS_2%]==[] netsh interface ip add dns "Local Area Connection" %DNS_2% index=2
ECHO.
netsh interface ip show config
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO again

:DHCP
ECHO.
@ECHO Setting up Local Area Connection for DHCP Configuration
netsh interface ip SET address "Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
netsh interface ip SET dns "Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
ECHO.
ipconfig
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO again

:SB200
ECHO.
@ECHO 10.10.241.205
netsh interface ip delete dns "Local Area Connection" all
netsh interface ip SET address "Local Area Connection" static 10.10.241.205 255.255.255.0 10.10.241.201 1
netsh interface ip show config
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO again

:SB600
ECHO.
@ECHO 192.168.0.102
netsh interface ip delete dns "Local Area Connection" all
netsh interface ip SET address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.102 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
netsh interface ip show config
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO again

:T_U
ECHO.
@ECHO 172.16.233.215
netsh interface ip delete dns "Local Area Connection" all
netsh interface ip SET address "Local Area Connection" static 172.16.233.215 255.255.255.0 172.16.233.214 1
netsh interface ip show config
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO again

:T_P
ECHO.
@ECHO 10.10.10.10
netsh interface ip delete dns "Local Area Connection" all
netsh interface ip SET address "Local Area Connection" static 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1 1
netsh interface ip show config
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO :again
```

*P.S. I'v been looking for the person who originally wrote this code. Incase said person reads this, Thanks.*